# Non Hausdorff complex manifold?

Tags: general-topology, complex-manifolds

Suppose there is a topological space $X$ equipped with an atlas making it into a complex manifold. Is it true that this implies automatically that $X$ is Hausdorff ? I have heard it is the case for Riemann surfaces, although I don't have a reference for it. Is it true in higher dimension ?

EDIT as remarked in the comments and answer, I was mistaken. This does not seem true even in dimension one.

Comment: No, we can take the plane with a doubled origin, and the natural charts to get a non-Hausdorff "complex manifold".

Comment: Did you perhaps confuse Hausdorff with second countability? A Riemann surface is necessarily second countable (deep theorem by Rado).

Comment: yes, I guess you are right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, and I'm not even sure why that would be true with Riemann surfaces. I mean, let $M$ be any manifold of any type. Let $x$ be some point in $M$.

$$M' = (M \sqcup M )/\sim$$

Where where we quotient every point not equal to $x$ with it's twin in the other copy. This is a generalization of the "line with two origins". This has a pretty immediate non-Hausdorff manifold structure as a manifold of the same type as $M$. Any additional structure: complex, Riemannian, Kahler, should carry through unless I'm being very silly.

The thing is just that in almost any book you ever see, when they say a manifold they mean a Hausdorff manifold.

Comment: thanks ! I confused second countability with hausdorffness apparently...